# Vue.js nodeName variable

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to create a template such as

```
<{{ headerType }}>{{ text }}</{{ headerType }}>
```

and bind data

```
{
  headerType: 'h3', // or h1, h2...
  text: 'Header text'
}
```

The resulting template is not rendered as HTML so that I end up having `<h3>Header text</h3>` as text on my page.

Is there a pretty way of doing this?

Comment: use `v-html` in a parent element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a component with a render function.

```js
Vue.component('heading', {
  props: {
    level: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
      'h' + this.level,   // tag name
      this.$slots.default // array of children
    )
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    level: "1",
    text: 'hi'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
    <select v-model="level"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>
    <heading :level="level">
        {{text}}
    </heading>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following:

```
<div id="demo">
  <div v-html="'<' + headerType +'>' + text + '</' + headerType + '>'"></div>
</div>
```

You can move this string creation part in separate method or computed property as well, for better readability.

see working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zm0130j8/).